# Prove that the coefficient of $x^n$ in the polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}y_iℓ_i(x)$ is $\sum_{i=0}^{n}y_i\prod_{j=0, i\neq j}^{n}(x_i-x_j)^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, interpolation

**Prove that the coefficient of $x^n$ in the polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}y_iℓ_i(x)$ is $\sum_{i=0}^{n}y_i\prod_{j=0, i\neq j}^{n}(x_i-x_j)^{-1}$**

I know that $ℓ_i(x)=\prod_{j=0, i\neq j}^{n}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$ where P are obtained from the Lagrange interpolation, then this is reduced to finding the $x^n$ coefficient of $\sum_{i=0}^{n}y_i\prod_{j=0, i\neq j}^{n}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$, how can you do this easily?

Comment: Evaluate $x^n\ell_i(1/x)$ at $x=0$. You have that $x^{n}\ell_i(1/x)=\prod_{j=0,i\neq j}^{n}\frac{1-xx_j}{x_i-x_j}$. Evaluating at $x=0$, you get $\prod_{j=0,i\neq j}^{n}\frac{1}{x_i-x_j}$.

Comment: @totoro 
Please explain better what you want to say that I do not understand very well.

Comment: If you have a polynomial $f(x)=3x^2+4x+5$ and you compute $g(x)=x^2f(1/x)=3+4x+5x^2$, then evaluating this at $x=0$, gives you the coefficient of the term of degree $n$ of $f$, which is $g(0)=3$. Doing this procedure with $\ell_i(x)$ gives you their leading coefficient. Multiplying by $y_i$ and adding you get the leading coefficient of $p(x)$.